# Has Khachiyan/Porkolob's convex integer optimization been implemented?

Tags: ds.algorithms, integer-programming, convex-optimization, software, implementation

Khachiyan and Porkolab in 'Integer optimization on convex semialgebraic sets' gave an $O(ld^{ O(k^4)})$ algorithm to minimize a degree $d$ form with integer coefficients of binary length at most $l$ over integer points in a convex set in $\Bbb R^k$. Has this ever been implemented in any package?